# Lisp : How do I install gcl in mac

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, gnu-common-lisp

I have Mac OSX 10.8.4. I have cloned the git repo of gcl and as per the readme I ran the ./configure.

But, I am getting the following error :

```
configure: error: Cannot build with randomized sbrk. Your options:
 - upgrade to a kernel/libc that knows about personality(ADDR_NO_RANDOMIZE)"
 - recompile your kernel with CONFIG_COMPAT_BRK (if it has that option)"
 - run sysctl kernel.randomize_va_space=0 before using gcl
```

Have tried the third option(for the others I am clueless and didn't get any solution even after googling). Can anyone please tell me how should I install gcl or go about getting a developing environment lisp ?

Comment: I would just get Clozure CL, if your software does not require GCL. GCL maintenance is not very active and probably also not concentrating much on Mac OS X. Clozure CL is actively supported and developed by a bunch of Mac experts. The step up is to buy LispWorks - a bit expensive - which runs great on Macs and comes with even better GUI-based development tools.

Comment: I second Clozure CL, but don't use the AppStore version. LispWorks is way too expensive. clisp is available through homebrew though I haven't tried it personally.

Comment: Clozure CL is working great on Macs, absolutely. Another good option is SBCL.

Comment: There is a free version of LispWorks Personal Edition (http://www.lispworks.com/downloads/).  I've found that IDE to be much easier to use than Emacs/SLiME, sbcl or any other Lisp setup.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your kind support, I have installed clisp using brew and have finally got it working. Thanks to Rainer your comment was really helpful.

Comment: I'll just add that for raw speed, nothing beats SBCL, at least for the things I usually do.

Comment: gcl seems to be getting some maintenance (latest release is just a week old as I type this), but still won't build on OS X.

Comment: Have you tried with homebrew? https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/clisp.rb

Comment: Do you mind posting an answer if you solved your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clisp(can be installed through homebrew) was good enough for getting a hands on experience in lisp.